# Prove that if $S,T:V\to V$ are linear maps such that $\operatorname{ker}ST=\{0\}$ then $\operatorname{ker}S=\{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Prove that if $V$ is a finite dimension space and $S,T:V\to V$ are linear maps such that $\operatorname{ker}ST=\{0\}$ then $\operatorname{ker}S=\{0\}$

Since $\operatorname{ker}T\subseteq \operatorname{ker}ST=\{0\}$ and $\dim V=\dim V$ then $T$ is isomorphism.

Therefore $\operatorname{Im}T=V$ and for any $s\in \operatorname{Im}S$ exists $v\in V$ such that $T(v)=u$ and $S(u)\in \operatorname{Im}S$.

Suppose $u\neq0$ exists such that $S(u)=0$ then $S(T(v))=0$ while $T(v)\neq 0$. But this is a contradiction since $\operatorname{ker}ST=\{0\}$.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam yes it is, I added this in the post now

Comment: (Note it's not necessarily true if $V$ is infinite dimensional - for example if $T$ is the right-shift operator and $S$ is the left-shift operator on the space of sequences $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct except that I don't see why you need the second line of your proof. This is because for any $u \in V$, there exists $v \in V$ such that $Tv=u$. It doesn't matter if $u$ is in the Image of $S$ or not. In the first line you mean that $\dim(V) \lt \infty$ I suppose.

You arrived at a contradiction by showing that $v\ne0$ is in $\ker{ST}$.

Comment: I wanted to show that there's a contradiction in order to be more rigorous I guess.